# How to get correct path of configuration file?

Tags: java, configuration

I created a Java project that contains three configuration file

- log4j.XML
- QueueConfig.xml
- rabbitmq.properties

I put these three files into a resource folder.

Then I created a jar file of my project. This jar file is added to another project. It isn't able to find the correct location of the configuration files.

My file structure:

[image]

Thanks

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use it like.

```
ClassFromWhichYouAreACcessingTheseFiles.class.getResources("resources/log4j.properties");
```

than if you add this jar to another project you will be able to access it.

Comment: thanks.i try but it return null value.URL url= this.getClass().getResource("resources/log4j.xml");

Comment: @sam don't use this, try `ClassFromWhichYouAreACcessingTheseFiles.class.getResources("/resources/log4j.properties");`

Answer (score 1):

If your config files end up in the WEB-INF/classes folder

```
ClassFromWhichYouAreACcessingTheseFiles.class.getClassLoader().getResources("log4j.properties");
```

otherwise it include the "package-path" from the ClassFromWhichYouAreACcessingTheseFiles

Comment: thanks,it works.it's required to my jar file contains resources folder.