# Reading Json config from different directory of same package and getting its path

Tags: java, json

I'm working on a project and I'm trying to read Json Config file.
But the problem is I'm getting java.io.FileNotFoundException exception whenever I run my class.
My Project Structure is

```
project |
---> configuration |
-------> Json file directory |
-----------> Json File |
---> src
------> My class directory|
---------> MyClass |
---> test |
------> My testClass Directory |
----------> MyClassTest |
```

My code for reference :

```
try {
            final InputStream pathToConfigurableJarvisTagFile = new FileInputStream("/configuration/jarvis-tags/ConfigurableJarvisTags.json");

            fileReader = new InputStreamReader(pathToConfigurableJarvisTagFile, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

I got the below exception

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /configuration/jarvis-tags/ConfigurableJarvisTags.json (No such file or directory)
    [junit] java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /configuration/jarvis-tags/ConfigurableJarvisTags.json (No such file or directory)
```

It is not able to find the file. How do I modify the above code to read config file/get the path of file from a different folder?

I tried this [How to get correct path of configuration file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4164011/how-to-get-correct-path-of-configuration-file)

Comment: Look at [Java says FileNotFoundException but file exists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19307622/). But having shown this, you're probably much better off getting the data not as a file, but rather as a resource:  [open resource with relative path in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/573679/). Also, check out [What's the difference between a Resource, URI, URL, Path and File in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27845223/)

Comment: Your directory structure is hard to read, can you show a screenshot or otherwise improve it? I suspect this is as simple as the \path to your config \file you give the program, and the actual path, are different. But we can't tell without more details.

Comment: In this `resourcesloader.class.getClass().getResource("repository/SSL-Key/cert.jks").toString()
` the resourcesloader is the class where I want to read my config file from? Or it should be config file class?

Answer (score 0):

It is trying to load the file from:
`/configuration/jarvis-tags/ConfigurableJarvisTags.json`
i.e. from the root.

You either need to make sure you current directory (when running the code) is `projects` and use the relative path:
`configuration/jarvis-tags/ConfigurableJarvisTags.json`

or (better) explicitly resolve and use the full path:
`/full/path/to/project/configuration/jarvis-tags/ConfigurableJarvisTags.json`